# Meteor Template.Subscribtion. How it actually work?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I have a this little code:

```
Template.video_item.onCreated(function(){
  var self = this;
  self.autorun(function() {
      self.subscribe('video', FlowRouter.getParam('_id'));
      self.subscribe('top_videos');
  });
});

Template.video_item.onRendered(function(){
   var video = Video.findOne(FlowRouter.getParam('_id'));
   video.upViews();
});
```

Pretty simple, and DOC's friendly. Right? 
When i go on router via link, the 'video' var store **Video** object. But when i do hot reload page with "f5" the 'video' variable is **undefined**. Route is fine. But subscribtion - not. Why?

This code does not work too . Or am I doing something wrong.

```
var self = this;
  self.autorun(function() {
      var subscription = self.subscribe('video', FlowRouter.getParam('_id'));
      self.subscribe('top_videos');
      if(subscription.ready()){
        console.log('Im ready!');
      }
  });
```

Comment: Likely the subscription is not ready yet on hot reload. Does the data appear eventually?

Comment: @MichelFloyd Yes, it is. And...code with .ready() not work too. 
Or...may be i use it wrong.

var self = this;
  self.autorun(function() {
      var subscription = self.subscribe('video', FlowRouter.getParam('_id'));
      self.subscribe('top_videos');
      if(subscription.ready()){
        console.log('Im ready!');
      }
  });